# Java - Filtrar repeticiones en un array de strings manteniendo el orden

Tags: java

Estoy trabajando con Java 8.

Necesito, teniendo un array de strings cuyo contenido desconozco y en el cual puede o no haber repeticiones, obtener ese contenido, sin repeticiones y sin alterar el orden original. Por ejemplo, si tuviera:

```
String[] strs = {"orange", "apple", "apple", "banana", "grape", "apple", "lemon"};
```

Debería obtener:

```
{"orange", "apple", "banana", "grape", "lemon"};
```

Actualmente uso el siguiente método para filtrar repeticiones, pero suele desordenar los elementos:

```
/**
 * Filters repeated strings in the array
 *
 * @param  arrStr
 * @return
 */
public static String[] filterRepeatedStr(String[] arrStr) {

    List<String> arr = Arrays.asList(arrStr);
    Set<String> hs   = new HashSet();
    hs.addAll(arr);

    return hs.toArray(new String[hs.size()]);
}
```

Comment: Usa un LinkedHashSet en lugar de HashSet y se mantendrá el orden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es el uso del `HashSet`, la opción es el uso de `LinkedHashSet`, ya que `LinkedHashSet` almacena los elementos en función del orden de inserción :

```
   String[] strs = {"orange", "apple", "apple", "banana", "grape", "apple", "lemon"};

     List<String> arr = Arrays.asList(strs);
    Set<String> hs   = new LinkedHashSet ();
    hs.addAll(arr);
```

Como resultado obtendrías:

```
   {orange, apple, banana, grape, lemon}
```

Algo importante a comentar es que usando `HashSet` se tiene mejor rendimiento pero no garantiza ningún orden en los elementos, en cambio `LinkedHashSet` si, pero se sacrifica el rendimiento.

Comment: Entiendo por tu respuesta que al usar *LinkedHashSet* no se va a alterar el orden de los elementos, desconozco como funcionan internamente estas clases.

Comment: @Orici usando HashSet no garantiza ningún orden en los elementos en cambio LinkedHashSet mantiene el orden inicial.

Answer (score 0):

Mediante el uso de Stream se hace sencillo.

```
public class FiltrarRepeticiones {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] strs = {"orange", "apple", "apple", "banana", "grape", "apple", "lemon"};
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(strs);
        Stream<String> listaNueva = list.stream().distinct();
        listaNueva.forEach(fruta -> System.out.println(fruta));   
    } 
}
```

> **Resultado:**
>   orange apple banana grape lemon

---

**Actualizo.**
Así se podría trabajar con las *interfaces funcionales*.
Voy a poner un ejemplo con la interfaz [UnaryOperator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/UnaryOperator.html), que recibe un tipo y devuelve un valor del mismo tipo.

```
public interface UnaryOperator<T> extends Function<T,T>
```

**Ej:**

```
public class UnaryOperatorTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> listaStr = 
                Arrays.asList("orange", "apple", "apple", "banana", "grape", "apple", "lemon");

        List<String> listStrAct = operadorUnaryStr(cadena -> cadena.toUpperCase(), listaStr);
        listStrAct.stream().distinct().forEach(str -> System.out.print(str+" "));

    }

    public static List<String> operadorUnaryStr(
                UnaryOperator<String> unaryOpt, List<String> lista){
        List<String> listaActualizada = new ArrayList<>();
        lista.forEach(str -> listaActualizada.add(unaryOpt.apply(str)));
        return listaActualizada;  
    }

}
```

> *Y obtendríamos como resultado...*
>   ORANGE APPLE BANANA GRAPE LEMON

Comment: Estaría bien cuando se votara negativamente, explicar los motivos. Que se puede entender, sobre todo para aprender. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Con Streams se puede quitar valores repetidos y volver a tener un array sin crear otras colecciones. Ademas la libreria Arrays facilita mucho el trabajo de manipular arrays.

```
String[] strs = {"orange", "apple", "apple", "banana", "grape","apple","lemon"};
String[] str = Arrays.stream(strs)
            .distinct()
            .toArray(String[]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str));
```